# A Boolean is required here in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to show "NoData" if its value is less than Zero and "Commission" if its value is greater than Zero. When i show "String" its gave me error the boolean is required here and then if i do `toText{VBookingCommission.MarketingPersonnelCommission1}` it gaves me Error Convert it to String

This is my Query for Crystal Report

```
        if({VBookingCommission.MarketingPersonnelCommission1}<0)
           then "NOData" else "Commission";
```

If i do this its working Fine

```
        if({VBookingCommission.MarketingPersonnelCommission1}<0)
             then true else false;
```

Comment: where did you write this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a code like what you need. in formula edit form set visual basic instead of crystal report.
code:
 
`if({VBookingCommission.MarketingPersonnelCommission1}<0) then formula="NOData" else if({VBookingCommission.MarketingPersonnelCommission1}>0) then formula="Commission"`

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that i was putting in under Suppress i need to put it in Formulas and i start working just fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happing because the variable type is Boolean. Either you need to use `true` or `false`.
OR
change the type of data of the variable and update the Data source using 'Verify Databases' or 'Set Datasource Location'